# How to display date in dd/mm/yyyy format?

Tags: java

I am to new to Java. I want to display date in `dd/mm/yyyy` format. When I print date using `new Date()` function it gives me Sting which I don't want. Say I want to print today's date it gives me `Sat Jan 24 08:17:41 IST 2015` but I want output as `24/1/2015`

Comment: Dude, there are *hundreds* of existing SO Question on converting dates to strings in specific formats.  Why couldn't you search for and read one of those?  Please always search before you ask.  It saves everyone's time ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
String date = sdf.format(new Date());
```

Answer (score 0):

There you have one way to do it: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/format.html

So basically you can define the format in an formatter and use that to convert
the date into a string:

```
try {
    DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM d yyyy  hh:mm a");
    String out = departure.format(format);
    System.out.printf("LEAVING:  %s (%s)%n", out, leavingZone);
}
catch (DateTimeException exc) {
    System.out.printf("%s can't be formatted!%n", departure);
    throw exc;
}
```